# Change fontsize on plotly slider

Tags: python, plotly

I want to change the font size on the slider label.  I tried:

```
fig.update_layout(sliders=dict(fontsize= 16))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I believe that this should work for you now as it is only changing the font attributes for the slider.

```
    sliders = [dict(
active=10,
currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
pad={"t": 50},
steps=steps,
font=dict(
    family="Courier New, monospace",
    size=18,
    color="RebeccaPurple"
))]
fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders
)
```

Comment: Hmm I think you may have misunderstood my question.  I'm asking about the font on the slider in plotly.

Comment: The code that I have provided seems to work fine to change the font on the slider, I have just edited my code to implement it into a slider to make it easier to see.

Comment: This changes the font of everything.  I wanted to change just the slider.  I'll post my full code.

Answer (score 0):

```
sliders = [
           dict(font={'size': 20}
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders
)
```